# Mysql Join and count for each categories

Tags: join, mysqli, count

Hi I have a tables like this
**exams**

```
id | exam_name
1  | computer science
2  | Environment science
```

**exam_students**

```
id | exam_id | student_name
1  | 1       | Josh
2  | 1       | Michael
3  | 1       | John
```

I just need to join and count the total students of each exam and output something like this

```
exam_name          | total_students |
computer science   | 3              |
Environment science| 0              |
```

Thank you for your any help and suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
    a.exam_name, count(b.id) AS total_students
FROM
    exams a
LEFT JOIN exam_students b ON a.id = b.exam_id
GROUP BY
    a.id
```

Hope this help

Comment: no its only gives "computer science  | 3 " it will ignore Environment science